# How to use PowerMock in Android projects?

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, powermock

I created a new Android test project.  I downloaded powermock-mockito-junit-1-1.5.zip from https://code.google.com/p/powermock/downloads/list.  I added all of the libraries to the test project's `libs` folder. The test class is a very simple object:

```
package com.test.test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import android.util.Log;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestTestAndroid {

    public void testRuns() {
        Log.e("test", "Test case is called");
    }
}
```

Then, I try running the project from Eclipse, or making the project from the command line.  I get the same error:

`Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description;`

As it turns out, both `junit-4.8.2.jar` and `mockito-all-1.9.5.jar` define `org.hamcrest.Description`.  I must include the Mockito jar for obvious reasons - I need Mockito.  A different version of JUnit is provided by Android, but it is an old version that does not include the `@RunWith` annotation.

Can someone answer how to use powermock and mockito in an Android project, without the conflicting `org.hamcrest.Description` problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, you can't use PowerMock in the Dalvik VM.

PowerMock works by running your test under a custom ClassLoader which uses [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) to modify the bytecode of your classes.  This works okay on a normal JVM, but on Dalvik the bytecode and class format are different, so this approach doesn't work.  PowerMock would need to be rewritten to use [Dexmaker](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) instead of Javassist - this would be decidedly non-trivial, and I don't see anything like this on the PowerMock [issues list](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/list).

Comment: If you can't use PowerMock on Android, do you know any other way to stub a static method on Android?

Comment: @lowellk There's a workaround. Have a non-static method call the static method, and then stub it out. For example, if `HttpConstants.getUrl()` is a static method, write another method: `String getUrl() { return HttpConstants.getUrl(); }` Then, you can stub that method out.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, I find that this is completely untrue (at least with the latest version).

In my gradle setup for the module where I want to test my code I have

```
// Mockito and PowerMock
androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.0') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'objenesis'
}
```

and everything runs fine. As long as I use:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) @PrepareForTest(ClassToMock.class)
```

to annotate my class (eg, can't run it with Robolectric, still fine in CI environments)

Comment: Can you post your full gradle setup? I cannot find the import for PowerMockRunner.class

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because it is part of our company's application, but it should be in there, via import `import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;` just make sure if you are using androidTestCompile, your instrumentation tests using this import are in the androidTest folder, etc

Comment: ok, but to have that import I need to have the following compile in gradle:
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'
This is causing me a lot of problems like: "Multiple dex files defined..."

Comment: It sounds like the short int limit is being hit, so you might need to use multidex enabled or just check your files using `gradle -q app:dependencies` at the root of your project in the command line to see what imports are overlapping. Also, note that the `powermock-mockito-release-full` import contains Mockito, so you do not need to import both.

Comment: How did you run the test? I'm trying to use Easymock+PowerMock, with ActivityInstrumentationTest or plain jUnit test, but I have always the same error


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension API internal error: org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in classpath.

Comment: I get the exception 'I/TestRunner: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension API internal error: org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in classpath.' when I annotate with PowerMockRunner. Does any one else see it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I see `Program type already present: org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers`. And I added the exclude module already.