# PowerMock - Mock a Singleton with a Private Constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, singleton, powermock, easymock

I'm using PowerMock with EasyMock, and wondered how I might mock a singleton with a private constructor?

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    public int crazyServerStuff() { ... }
}
```

And a class which uses this:

```
public class Thing {
    public Thing() {}

    public int doStuff(Singleton s) {
        return s.crazyServerStuff() + 42;
    }
}
```

How might I mock the `crazyServerStuff` method?

I've tried the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Singleton.class)
public class ThingTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testDoStuff() {
        MemberModifier.suppress(MemberModifier.constructor(Singleton.class));
        Singleton mockSingleton = PowerMock.createMock(Singleton.class);

        ...
    }
}
```

But I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class Singleton`

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I don't think this is possible for Android - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737313/349831).

If you're not on Android, it looks like [this](http://buckybits.blogspot.ie/2011/11/testing-singletons-and-static-classes.html) is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should suppress the constructor, but rather mock it:

```
PowerMock.expectNew(Singleton.class).andReturn(mockObject)
```

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

Comment: Thanks, but how do I then create the `mockObject` to return? Does that not require calling `createMock`?

Comment: You should be able to use the #createMock() call as above

Comment: That throws the exception in the question :(

Comment: Try adding your test class to prepare annotation: 
@PrepareForTest({Singleton.class, ThingTest.class})

Comment: I still get the exception. Thanks for looking in to this! Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What versions of PowerMock & EasyMock are you using? I just tried your code and it works for me with Powermock 1.5.6 & EasyMock 3.1. Also, which line exactly throws that exception?

Comment: I'm using EasyMock 3.3 and PowerMock 1.5.6. I think the problem is that I'm on Android and so the java bytecode is different, so powermock doesn't work :/