# PowerMock Enum Private Constructor Mocking

Tags: java, powermock, powermockito

Unable to mock private enum constructor.

Please find below MySingleton enum with private constructor, in this constructor I am creating service which makes remote call. In my test i want to mock this constructor so that in junit execution my test will not connect remote server.

Using powermock to mock enum constructor. I am able to inject enum instance using Whitebox class of powermock. Also able to get mock service when mock instance is called.

To mock invocation of private constructor using **whenNew(MySingleton.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(instance)** but private constructor of enum is not getting mock and test is trying to connect to remote service.

How to mock invocation of private constructore in enum ?

```
public enum MySingleton {
Instance;

private MyService service

private MySingleton () {
  // service initialization. service connect to remote server
  service = new MyService();
  System.out.println("Constructor Invoke");
}

public Myservice getService() {

return service;
}

}

public class DriverClass {

public void initService() 
 {
  MySingleton.Instance.getService();

 }

}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MySingleton.class)
public class DriverClassTest {

@Mock private Myservice service;
private MySingleton instance;

@before
public void setup() {
instance = mock(MySingleton.class);
Whitebox(MySingleton.class,"Instance",instance);
whenNew(MySingleton.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(instance);
}

@test
public void testInitSerice()
 {
when(instance.getService()).thenReturn(service);

new DriverClass().initService();

}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108194/powermock-mock-a-singleton-with-a-private-constructor#27108456?